# Input Date binding

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to bind to :

```
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

This works perfect:

```
<input type="date" format-value="MM/dd/yyyy" @bind="MyObject.DOB">
```

What I need to work is,

```
<input type="date" format-value="MM/dd/yyyy" value="@MyObject.DOB"  @onchange="@( (args) => { MyObject.DOB = args.Value.ToString().TryDateConvert(); MyMethod();})">
```

Or

```
<input type="date" format-value="MM/dd/yyyy" value="@MyObject.DOB"  @onchange="@( (args) => DOBChanged(args))">
```

&

```
public void DOBChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var myVal =e.Value.ToString();
    MyObject.DOB = myVal.TryDateConvert();
    MyMethod();
}
```

I've tried a few variations, but no matter what it will bind to the MyObject.DOB, but it will not display in the textbox.

It will reset back to MM/DD/YYYY. I've used this way on other controls, but for some reason the date is throwing it for a loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out Chris Sainty's blog post [here](https://chrissainty.com/building-custom-input-components-for-blazor-using-inputbase/), he discusses building up custom input components (Among other things) and this might point you in the right direction. The short version is you will be making a component that is intelligent enough to handle the logic for you, and you could provide format strings, etc. as component parameters if needed.

Comment: I was just hoping there was an easy solution. It seems weird this doesn't work.

Comment: You might also try using the InputDate native component, using Bind-Value to bind to your property, and then do your parse logic and run your other method in the property setter. I've seen that nullable datetimes can be a bit tricky to bind to, but it's worth a google search and a try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="date">` is not really working well with format-value attributes you can read more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date.

You can try this -

```
<input type="date" value="@MyObject.DOB.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" @onchange="@( (args) => DOBChanged(args))">

public void DOBChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var myVal = e.Value.ToString();
        MyObject.DOB = DateTime.Parse(myVal);
        MyMethod();
    }
```

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. Thank you.